# Mixing Ruby on Rails and ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, web-hosting

I’ve scoured the Internet via Google and could not find if it is possible to host ASP .Net and Ruby on Rails on the same server!

Do you know if it is possible?

If not, would I be able to do this?

– **www.abc.com** – redirects to **Page A** (**hosted on Ruby on Rails server**)

– **jobs.abc.com** OR **www.abc.com/jobs** - redirects user to **Page B** (**hosted on ASP .Net server**)

So from the user point of view, they’re both under the same domain name and appear seamless? So perhaps **jobs.abc.com** points to a different IP address.

Has anyone done this before?

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you managed to do it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same physical computer can host RoR and ASP.NET at the same time.

To merge two apps on separate platforms and make them appear as one seamless site is a little more challenging. One not very nice option is to use IFRAMEs to render one site (B) inside another's (A) pages, allowing the top-level URL to still show A's domain, etc.

It sounds like finding out more about the issue you are trying to solve would be a good idea, as going down this road is likely to create a mess in the future, and should be avoided if at all possible.

You can also use sub-domains like you suggested, so that the domain names are similar but not exactly the same.

You will also need to consider how to share authentication, etc., across sites.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

By hosting on the same computer, do you know of any Web hosting provider that does that?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve. www.abc.com goes to my Job Q&A site (Shapado) while jobs.abc.com goes to the Job Search pages. I intended to have all other pages other than Shapado page to be in ASP .Net. So I would prefer to host them all together in one server if such provider exist. Otherwise sub-domain that goes to a different server might work? But I have never tried making the subdomain point to a different server. Is it possible? Any implications? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll not find a host that supports both I guess.

I'm thinking of something similar. Seems a Windows VPS hosting is the way to go, and then I can install Ruby to IIS as FastCGI filter, or even have another  server side by side but I don't expect this to work flawlessly when both servers will need to listen to port 80 (doable I guess, but probably troubling).

BTW, for the jobs.abc.com scenario you don't need the two apps on the same server. You can have them on two servers and manage the difference via DNS.